# How can I get white on black buttons working in topbar in both iOS7 and iOS6 with Trigger.io?

Tags: button, trigger.io

Using black tint with light_content style:

```
forge.topbar.removeButtons()
forge.topbar.setStatusBarStyle("light_content")
forge.topbar.setTint([0,0,0,255])
```

Adding buttons. Images are black on transparent .png's:

```
{
   icon: 'images/info.png'
 , tint: [255,255,255,255]
 , position: 'right'
}
```

This works for iOS7, however in iOS6 shows black on a white background within the button. I've tried reversing the image, white on transparent, white on black - and I can't get white on black button images to work on both iOS6 and iOS7.

Is there a way to create the images or specify the forge API calls to get this to work? Or is it a bug in the forge topbar implementation?

Comment: Define "a combination that works"

Comment: Edited question to clarify. Basically I can't get white on black to work for both iOS7 AND iOS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For white on black buttons (based on white (or black) on transparent png) toggle the tint based on user agent detection provided by Connor:

```
var tint = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i) !== null)
     ? [255,255,255,255] 
     : [0,0,0,255];
```

Also, image size for topbar icons should be 44x44 pixels, **not** 64x64 as may be inferred from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to changes in the underlying way iOS 7 displays both the topbar and tabbar. The API provided by Trigger tries to be as close as possible between versions, but it sometimes has to appear differently to support new platform features.

The easiest way to do what you want is to detect iOS 7 and run different code, you can do that as follows:

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i) !== null) {
     // iOS 7 specific code
 } else {
     // iOS 6 and lower specific code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the work-around. Since Tigger.IO is providing abstraction to iOS v Android, I wouldn't expect to have to provide a hack for different versions of iOS.